# ionic 3 - How to retrieve incoming phone call number?

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I am trying to get incoming phone call number in ionic 3. I am doing this with https://www.npmjs.com/package/cozzbie.plugin.phonecalltrap. 
It's detect the phone state well but not returning the incoming phone number.

I am using the code bellow,

```
declare var PhoneCallTrap:any;

if (PhoneCallTrap) 
    {
      PhoneCallTrap.onCall(function(obj) {
        var callObj = JSON.parse(obj),
            state = callObj.state,
            callingNumber = callObj.incomingNumber;

        switch (state) {
            case "RINGING":
                console.log("Phone is ringing =" + callingNumber);
                break;
            case "OFFHOOK":
                console.log("Phone is off-hook");
                break;

            case "IDLE":
                console.log("Phone is idle");
                break;
        }
      });
    }
```

Is there any other idea or plugin to retrieve phone call number

Comment: I would suspect that accessing phone numbers via code is subject to a particular's platform policy. Normally things like IMEI, phone numbers etc are subject to certificates and not every app (not 3rd party apps) can access that data...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right plugin and your code is fine but you just need to add right android permission to access data from mobile. For that follow this code.

Add this plugin to your project:

- [Android permissions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions)

Open app.module.ts file add like this:

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';

providers: [ AndroidPermissions ],
```

open homePage.ts file import AndroidPermissions and add this code:

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';

declare var PhoneCallTrap: any;

constructor(public androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions){
  this.checkPermissionCall();
  this.checkPermissionREAD_CONTACTS();
}

//READ_PHONE_STATE
checkPermissionCall() {
  this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE).then(
    success => {
      //if permission granted
      this.phonecalls();
    },
    err => {
      this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE).
        then(success => {
          this.phonecalls();
        },
          err => {
            console.log("cancelled")
          });
    });
  this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE]);
}

//READ_PHONE_STATE
checkPermissionREAD_CONTACTS() {
  this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_CONTACTS).then(
    success => {
      //if permission granted
    },
    err => {
      this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_CONTACTS).
        then(success => {
        },
          err => {
            console.log("cancelled")
          });
    });
  this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_CONTACTS]);
}

//phone calls
phonecalls() {
  PhoneCallTrap.onCall(function (obj) {

    var callObj = JSON.parse(obj),
      state = callObj.state,
      callingNumber = callObj.incomingNumber;

    switch (state) {
      case "RINGING":
        console.log("Phone is ringing", callingNumber);
        break;
      case "OFFHOOK":
        console.log("Phone is off-hook");
        break;

      case "IDLE":
        console.log("Phone is idle");
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

I try like you but I am not able to get number but after hard work and search I got this and with this, you will get number and state.

Hope it helps you :)